# Getting external R libraries to work from rpy2 in pyspark

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, cluster-computing, pyspark

From pyspark worker nodes when I try to import an R library like zoo, it errors out.

Heres an example:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
def mapper(x):
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    try:
        importr('zoo')
        return 'Success!'
    except:
        raise ValueError('Import Failed')
rdd.map(mapper).collect() #errors out
```

But when I run it using pyspark --master local, it works.

Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is R and all of the packages installed on the worker nodes? That should be one thing. It also feels a bit verbose to run R code in Python, to then ship that to Spark which is run in Scala to hopefully get some performance benefits. What is the exact usecase for this?

Comment: @cantdutchthis : Gain in performance should factor in developer time and the number of times the implementation is run. The approach might make sense for exploratory or research work.